# bootstrap 4.0 navbar links not redirecting with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

Hello I am working with bootstrap 4.0,

I have this code for my navbar

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
 <li class="nav-item">
            @Html.ActionLink("Manage assistants", "Index", "Assistant", new { @class = "nav-link" })
        </li>
....
```

My problem is that when I try to redirect to assistantcontroller/index, the navbar link is redirecting to  localhostxxx/?lenght=8

What is going on here? Am I missing something?

thanks

Comment: What does redirecting or not redirecting have to do with Bootstrap??

Comment: that when I use this version of bootstrap the link is not working..

Comment: A link is a link. Redirecting or not redirecting has nothing to do with Bootstrap whatsoever.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, however I think that I stated "bootstrap " and "link" in the tittle

Comment: You haven't posted any actual Bootstrap code i.e. no output HTML. And yet, you are trying to blame Bootstrap for "not redirecting" a link. Bootstrap does NOT handle any kind of redirecting or not redirecting in the navbar whatsoever. The navbar will use whatever links you'll give it. It won't apply any changes to your link. Except for adding and removing the `active` class which is css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) where the 3rd parameter is the `routeValues` values.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Because your passing a `string`, and a string has one property name `Length`, it generates `?lenght=8` as a query string (although I assume you have a typo, since "Assistant" contains 9 characters so it would be generating `?length=9`)

Change you method to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage assistants", "Index", "Assistant", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

so that your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```